# BASH printf array with field separator and newline on last entry

Tags: bash, printf

How can I print out an array in BASH with a field separator between each value and a newline at the end.

The closest I can get with a single printf is `printf '%s|' "${arr1[@]}"` where | is the field separator.  The problem with this is there is no line break at the end. Any combination of \n I try to put in there either puts in a line break on every entry or none at all!

Is there a way of doing it on one line or do I need to use `printf '%s|' "${arr1[@]}";printf "\n"`

Thanks,

Geraint

Comment: Or `printf '%s|' "${arr1[@]}"; echo`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, you need two commands for this. `printf '%s|' "${array[@]}"; echo` is perfectly conventional.

Alternately, if you don't want the trailing `|`, you can temporarily modify `IFS` to use your chosen separator as its first character, and use `"${array[*]}"`:

```
IFS="|$IFS"; printf '%s\n' "${array[*]}"; IFS="${IFS:1}"
```

Comment: Or just `(IFS="|$IFS"; printf '%s\n' "${array[*]}")`, using a subshell to localize the change to `IFS`.

Comment: Or just `printf '%s\n' "${array[@]}"`

Comment: @ϹοδεMεδιϲ, that prints one array element per line, which is not what the OP is asking for; they want the whole array on one line (with a given separator -- in this case, the pipe character -- between them), with a newline at the end of that single line.

Comment: Sorry, I misread that one! This one would work `(IFS="|"; echo "${array[*]}")` or you can avoid the sub-shell with a function `join_array() { local IFS="$1"; shift; echo "$*"; }` followed by `join_array '|' "${array[@]}"`

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to have the `|` be printed, you could also remove it and just put in a space or whatever seperator you want to use (e.g. , or -):

`printf '%s ' "${arr1[@]}" ; printf '\n'`

If you need this more often you should use a function, due to writing the same code over and over is not the best way:

```
print_array ()
{
  # run through array and print each entry:
  local array
  array=("$@")
  for i in "${array[@]}" ; do
      printf '%s ' "$i"
  done
  # print a new line
  printf '\n'
}
```

usage:

```
print_array "${array_name[@]}"
```

example:

```
array01=(one two three)
print_array "${array01[@]}"
echo "this should be a new line"
```

output:

```
one two three
this should be a new line
```

Comment: You might want to also declare `local i`, to not be changing that variable's value in outer scope.

Answer (score 0):

The previous answers were nice.
Just wanted to mention that you can also do it easily in one command also:

`printf '%s ' "${arr1[@]}" $'\n'` (although kinda like `echo "${arr1[*]}"`)

Another one-liner could be:

`(IFS="|"; echo "${arr1[*]}")` - this sets the $IFS to "|", but in round brackets, thus the $IFS will not remain "|" throughout the rest of the script.

Also - to allow the $IFS as inline var, you can create a function:

```
print_array() {
  echo "${arr1[*]}"
}
```

Usage:

`IFS="|" print_array "${arr1[@]}"`

Explanation: "${arr1[*]}" prints all elements in just one string, with the first character of $IFS between all array elements.

just my two cents :)

have fun coding!... :)